# Fabric(crashlytics) plugin wont work in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, crashlytics, twitter-fabric, crashlytics-android

Im having trouble adding fabric to android studio. Right now I have android studio v1.5.1. I've tried installing "fabric" plugin from android studio, plugin section and also tried downloading the crashlytics plugin which installs well but when I sign in it updates to fabric and after that it goes disabled again. 
The issue is that I cannot click on the plugin/ the plugin I guess its not being initialized for some reason.
Does anyone have experienced such behavior with this plugin, and does anyone knows how can I fix this?

Here is how the plugin looks like:

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Just Restart may be work

Comment: @MD tried that too, but it does not work.. :(

Comment: is it successfully added, may be some thing missing, can you able to add once more

Comment: @Sree  tried that too, I will try once more but I dont think this will help

Comment: Do you get a release note after sign in your studio ?

Comment: @Sree how do you mean?

Comment: if you successfully added Fabric in android studio and  after sign in you can see a release  note

Comment: @Sree when I add fabric plugin it says its successfully installed and I need to restart android studio. I restart android studio and the plugin installed is not available to click on...

Comment: Android studio > File > Setting > Plugins , in search `Fabric for android studio` and install, this is how you did right ?

Comment: @Sree yes that is how i did it

Comment: it is working fine for me for the same version of android studio , sorry i cant get what is your problm

Comment: Guys, what's the final of this issue?

Comment: have you guys find any solution.